# Custom cassandra data directory

Tags: cassandra

I have installed cassandra and I'm trying to set the data directory alongside with the hints, the commitlog and saved_caches directories to `/home/mat/cassandra` instead of `/var/lib/cassandra`. **Do note that the home and the root directories are on different partitions.**

I've created the cassandra directory and I've set the ownership using `chown` to `cassandra:cassandra`` with the recursive option (`-R`). I've also tried to `chmod 777` the directory, **recursively** but it still doesn't work. I am using ArchLinux, with cassandra version 4.1.3. The error is listed in the following"

```
Jul 31 16:07:08 Arch cassandra[42943]: INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2023-07-31 16:07:08,100 StreamManager.java:260 - Storing streaming state for 3d or for 119156 elements
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: INFO  [main] 2023-07-31 16:07:09,663 NativeLibrary.java:186 - JNA mlockall successful
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: Exception (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError) encountered during startup: null
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:254)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:751)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:875)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/mat/cassandra; unable to start server
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1592)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<init>(CommitLog.java:108)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.construct(CommitLog.java:92)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<clinit>(CommitLog.java:77)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         ... 3 more
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: ERROR [main] 2023-07-31 16:07:09,691 CassandraDaemon.java:897 - Exception encountered during startup
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:254)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:751)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:875)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/mat/cassandra; unable to start server
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1592)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<init>(CommitLog.java:108)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.construct(CommitLog.java:92)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<clinit>(CommitLog.java:77)
Jul 31 16:07:09 Arch cassandra[42943]:         ... 3 common frames omitted
Jul 31 16:07:10 Arch systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Jul 31 16:07:10 Arch systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted, cassandra can't write on the specified directory. Usually, the cause is the permission on that directory. Cassandra needs to be able to write files and directories in the location specified.

What I suggest to do is:

1. I know that you changed the permission, but double-check the permission of your directory:

```
ls -ld /home/mat/cassandra
ls -l /home/mat/cassandra
```

Try to do it from the cassandra user. It may be that the cassandra user is not allowed to traverse the directory `mat`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory) for more details

2. Verify that the cassandra user can write files and directories in that directory.
   From the user cassandra:

```
mkdir /home/mat/cassandra/test
echo "This is a test" > /home/mat/cassandra/test/test.txt
cat /home/mat/cassandra/test/test.txt
```

Verify that the disk has enough free space and that you don't have any quotas preventing cassandra to write on it.

3. Check the audit logs on the node to see if you are running SELinux or AppArmour and if those are preventing cassandra to write on the disk.
4. Check the system logs if there is more info regarding this issue.

```
journalctl -u cassandra
```

5. Double-check the cassandra configuration, in particular, make sure that `data_file_directories`, `commitlog_directory` and `saved_caches_directory` are pointing to the correct directory in `cassandra.yaml`.
6. Double-check that cassandra (4.1.3) is compatible with your current setup and dependencies.
7. If the issue is still there, try totally deleting the directory `/home/mat/cassandra` and recreating it with the correct permissions. It may be possible that there have been some file or directory remnants from previous failed attempts.

After making any changes, remember to restart cassandra and check the logs to see if the issue is sorted or if there are new errors.

Lastly: remember that leaving cassandra data with global permission (chmod 777) is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: Well, I can't make the directory of my user (/home/mat) be owned by the cassandra group. Also I can't really login into the cassandra user because it doesn't accept the password of my root user... I have more than 169 gigabytes of storage available. That's why I'm trying to use cassandra on my home directory, compared to the root directory which only has 10gb of free space.

Comment: If the problem is the traverse permission (we are not sure yet) you will need to add the x (execution) permission to all directories, up to the cassandra data that you chose, so in this case `home` and `mat`. 

to login into the cassandra user you can `sudo su - cassandra` from your user or `su - cassandra` from root.